# ogr2ogr problem converting sosi fil to kml (or anything else)

Tags: ogr2ogr, sosi

I am trying to convert a SOSI file to KML, but I am getting the following error.

Error message

```
ERROR 4: Unrecognized geometry of type 5.
ERROR 4: Unrecognized geometry of type 20.
ERROR 1: Feature 168 referenced by 1474, but it was not initialized.
Aborted
```

I have tried different output formats but that do not seam to effect the error.

Are there any settings I can pass ogr2ogr to ignore or get around the errors?

Comment: You could try the -skipfailures option as documented in http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html `-skipfailures:
    Continue after a failure, skipping the failed feature.`

Comment: have you tried OGR info to see if it identifies anything odd with your source file? for ex: ogrinfo -al -so yourfilename

Comment: Ogrinfo gives the same error, and skipfailures don't help either